# Load javascript within a google map info window HTML content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to load a javascript script within a google map info window HTML content but, for reasons I don't understand, the script is not loaded.

I generate my infowindow like that :

```
var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({"content":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"\/path\/to\/js\"><\/script>"});
```

I precise that the javascript path has been tested.

Is it possible to load javascript script like that? If yes, what's wrong ?

Comment: Why not load the js file beforehand, eg in the head of the file? Also instead of escapes mix single and double quotes 'this "is" how'.

Comment: In fact, this is a little bit more complex... The info window content is an AJAX form. When I create the info window, I link the javascript resource to catch the form submission and send it in AJAX. The result of the AJAX request will be some JSON which wraps the reponse in HTML format. The "new" HTML needs some JS too, so I add the JS resource inside the "new" HTML. If I load the JS in the head of the file, when I will replace the info window HTML content, the JS won't never impact the "new" HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

If so, you could add the script anywhere else in the document besides the `infowindow` and use `.ajaxComplete()` to target some script to the `infowindow` after the ajax call has finished.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/